# How do I make a chrome extension load a website instead of window.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome app and the manifest loads a javascript document that looks like this

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any way that I can make it load a webpage **in its own chrome tab** instead of window.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out and this works for me. So, if you remove the window opening code and replace it with the window open command it will open the window without any redirects.

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
 window.open('https://www.example.com','_blank');
});
```